# Mapping CSV to a Model

Tags: java, xml, csv, mapping, jaxb

I am writing a simple CSV to XML processor in Java.

I am using JAXB to generate a model in java from a DTD. I need to process the CSV format into this model, and then marshall it into the XML that complies to the DTD. I am using JAXB to marhall the data from the Java model to the XML. I have to write the CSV-Model mapping myself.

At the moment, I can think of no better solution than to straight map the CSV to the Java model by reading it in and assigning it to the model in code.

Is there a more elegant solution to this that you can think of? Perhaps some reusable mapping library etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the flatpack library to parse CSVs into Java Models :
[Flatpack Project on sourceforge](http://flatpack.sourceforge.net/)

It is quite simple to use and use XML mappings to handle the CSV to Model projection (thus not inducing thight coupling between your csv and your java objects)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a straightforard mapping, you could use a thirdparty tool to directly map csv to xml (e.g. [csv2xml converter](http://csv2xml.sourceforge.net/)

Alternatively, read the csv file as a collection of maps with the 'key' as the name of the corresponding property in the java class. Then you can write a simple parser that will use reflection to set the csv values from the map into java objects.